# How to detect when Ctrl+R or tab is pressed on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, posix

I am trying to code a custom shell implementation in C++ for linux. In that, I have to implement a functionality which will run when Ctrl+R is pressed, and another when the Tab key is pressed. How do I detect when these two keys are pressed in C++? For Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Z, I used signal() function, but I am at a loss about what to do for these two.

Comment: You must turn off line buffering to implement that kind of functionality in your shell. This question may help you: [Getting raw input from console using C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698161/getting-raw-input-from-console-using-c-or-c)

Comment: If you don't mind using an external library, take a look at `ncurses`.